# How can I pass a standard, static variable from all views in Django?

Tags: django

I'm working on a blog application, and I want to have a sidebar that includes a list of all the months the blog has been in existence, to provide links to archives pages. Moreover, I'd like to make this automatically update when the month changes, rather than hardcoding it in the template. Of course, as far as I can tell, this means that I'll have to calculate the list of months in *every* view, and pass it into every template from every view.

I'd like to avoid this, if possible. Is there a way to calculate the list once and automatically apply it to every template, without having to explicitly pass it into the template from every view?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

There are a few possible solutions to your problem.

If you really want to have this on *every* page on your site a [context processor](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#writing-your-own-context-processors) is probably your best choice.  Context processors are basic way to inject data into all template contexts.  Be aware however that the context processor will be called on *every* request.

An alternative solution would be to create a [custom template tag](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/#howto-custom-template-tags) and use it on a shared base template for all of the pages you wish to have your sidebar.  Template tags are a bit more complex to create but they are more flexible.

With either solution you should also look at Django's [cache framework](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/cache/#topics-cache).  The cache framework makes it pretty easy to temporarily store your calculated values for a while to save some work on each request.

Comment: +1 for mentioning a custom template tag.  Unless this is a value you will use on literally every single page on the site, that's a better approach than a context processor.

Answer (score 4):

You want a template context processor

[Django - having middleware communicate with views/templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/557460/django-having-middleware-communicate-with-views-templates)

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/?from=olddocs#id1

Comment: -1 for apparently confusing middleware and template context processors, which have nothing to do with one other.

Comment: @Carl Meyer: I think the distinction is artificial, but I stand corrected.

Answer (score 0):

Django's template inheritance should cover this. You could create a base template that handles your sidebar functionality. Your other views extend this template.

Template Inheritance:
http://www.djangobook.com/en/1.0/chapter04/#s-template-inheritance

Comment: I already use template inheritance. How will that prevent me from having to pass the variable from each view into the template?

Comment: Sorry, meant to add in the answer above that you can generate/modify the base template from an external script that runs on the first of the month.

Answer (score 0):

A combination of custom template tags as mentioned previously and [template fragment caching](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/cache/?from=olddocs#template-fragment-caching) should do the trick.

Comment: +1 for fragment caching. Of course, you still have to get the data to the fragment should it be stale. We fixed the variable lookup in the template code to permit passing in functions. The function (curried so its params don't have to be passed) only gets called during fragment regeneration.