# Django equivalent to Flask g? Storing data on flask.g vs flask.request?

Tags: python, django

As far as I understand, `flask.g` offers temporary storage for the current request context (even though it's technically the application context as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15101229/5374468)). Accessing `g.my_data` during a request handler will ensure that `my_data` is for the current request. Does Django have something equivalent to this?

In my experimentation, Django's `request` object, which is passed into view functions, can be used the same as `flask.g`. I can simply use `request.my_data` and be ensured that `my_data` is for the current request.

Noticing, this I tried using `flask.request` similar to how I used `flask.g`, with equivalent results. This begs the question what does `flask.g` provide over `flask.request`, just peace of mind that `flask.request` attributes will not be overwritten?

FYI on use case, I'm sharing data between the actual request handler (flask) or view functions (django), and the middleware (django) or @before_request (flask) handlers.

[This source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/557540/5374468) seems to recommend putting data on the request.

As does [this source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15634187/5374468).

This leads me to answer yes for number 1 below, but wonder even more about number 2??

TLDR:

1. Can Django `request` be used equivalently to `flask.g`?
2. Can `flask.request` be used equivalently to `flask.g`, or what is the benefit of `flask.g` over `flask.request`?

Answer (score -1):

Django has the context_data and the get_context() method. To access this data override the get_context_data() method in your view like this.

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
  context = super(NameOfView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
  context.update(...)
  return context
```

Comment: I don't think you understood my use case. I want to set data in a middleware handler, that is then accessible in my view handler. I was planning on just adding it to the request object since that's what django does with request.user.

Comment: @Panda did you ever find a solution to this? I want to do the same thing

Comment: If I remember correctly, I used Django's `request` object